# Required VBA reference to use "Line Input"?

Tags: vba, file-io

A non Microsoft application that I am using supports VBA. I am trying to parse a file into an array, following example code I found [here](http://www.homeandlearn.org/images/text_files/open_file_code.gif):

```
Sub parseFile()

    Dim file As String
    file="c:/Users/Me/Documents/test.csv"

    Open file For Input As #1

    Dim data(2,5) As String '2,5 dummy values for test      
    Dim Line As Integer
    Line=0

    Do Until EOF(1)
       Line Input #1, LineFromFile
       LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
       Dim field As Integer
       For field = 0 To 5
        data(Line,field)=LineItems(field)
       Next field
    Loop

    Close #1
End Sub
```

I get "Invalid Instruction" for `Line Input #1, LineFromFile`.

Is this Excel-specific functionality? Is there a library I can include to use this? Should I be approaching this some other way?

Comment: It might help to know what non Microsoft product this is. Is it Libreoffice?

Comment: It's a ship design product called HECSALV. If there's anyone on SO with experience using it, I'll eat my shoes.

Comment: Fair enough. I know the feeling. I'm tired and not seeing the error right now, but I can tell you that this is not an Excel specific call, it's baked into the VBA core language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try commenting out these two lines

```
Dim Line As Integer
Line = 0
```

I think you're [shadowing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264773(v=office.15).aspx) the `Line` part of the  [Line Input Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264130(v=office.15).aspx). Basically, you're declared a local variable with the same name as a system function and the compiler is getting confused.

---

The file reading statements are not Excel specific, that are part of the core language and available without a reference. They're honestly old, clunky, and largely replaced by the `FileSystemObject`, which *does* require a reference.

Comment: Well that was silly of me. I suppose it would let me name a variable `if` too?

Comment: No. `If` is a reserved keyword while `Line` is not. Probably because `Line Input` predates VBA as we know it. I believe it came from the old Excel Macro language.